# Logout all users in openfire server

Tags: openfire

I have installed `openfire` chat on my server. sometimes some of my users stays connected even when they shutdown their computers, I means some of sessions stays connected. I'm using `pidgin` as client application. Now I have to stop `openfire` server and start it to solve this problem.

How can I prevent this? or Who can I disconnect all sessions?

Comment: https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on version that you use, there is bug in Openfire versions after 4.0.3 check it here:

https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-963

Answer (score 0):

As Sven already pointed out, Openfire does periodically check the connection to the clients. The relevant setting is

> **xmpp.client.idle**

More info at https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2053

Comment: tnx I test it..

Comment: I set it to 2s but it doesn't works..